# centos 7 server keeps restarting while building the docker images

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, centos7, restart, docker-ce

I have docker installed on centos & system.
I am able to download docker images using docker pull command.
but when I run the container using `docker run alpine`, the server restarts.
this is happening every time. 
I found this from /var/log/messages | grep docker

CODE

Below is my configuration:

```
 $ docker info
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 18.09.0
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: c4446665cb9c30056f4998ed953e6d4ff22c7c39
 runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 40
 Total Memory: 251.7GiB
 Name: CHMCISPRDOCKENG
 ID: XFPC:SYGF:Q3P7:M32Z:VRTX:TFGZ:YA43:NYSY:UGVK:PC2M:HVAU:TIM2
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode (client): false
 Debug Mode (server): false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  some-registry
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: API is accessible on http://127.0.0.1:2375 without encryption.
     Access to the remote API is equivalent to root access on the host. Refer
     to the 'Docker daemon attack surface' section in the documentation for
     more information: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Now when I run `docker pull alpine`. image is downloaded successfully.

But when I run `docker run -it alpine` , I am logged out from the server & server is restarted.
below are the logs when I ran `cat /var/log/messages | grep docker`.

```html
Dec 17 19:28:12 CHMCISPRDOCKENG systemd: Started docker.service.
Dec 17 19:28:12 CHMCISPRDOCKENG audispd: node=CHMCISPRDOCKENG type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1545055092.725:167): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=docker comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.023820157+05:30" level=warning msg="[!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!]"
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.043715041+05:30" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new containerd process" pid=15564
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.043788743+05:30" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.043810434+05:30" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.044206037+05:30" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.044227097+05:30" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.044283337+05:30" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420963f00, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.726282962+05:30" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=c4446665cb9c30056f4998ed953e6d4ff22c7c39 version=1.2.0
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.727202682+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.733393760+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.733593273+05:30" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.733607841+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.737142848+05:30" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs" error="modprobe aufs failed: "modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found.\n": exit status 1"
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.737165057+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.740458140+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.747800098+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.748343654+05:30" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter"
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.748359281+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.748378883+05:30" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter zfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter"
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.748386577+05:30" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"
Dec 17 19:28:16 CHMCISPRDOCKENG dockerd: time="2018-12-17T19:28:16.748392893+05:30" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter aufs in metadata plugin" error="modprobe aufs failed: "modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found.\n": exit status 1"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to be storage driver problem.
the configuration of the server was not supporting the default overlay2 storage driver for docker. changing it to devicemapper fixed things.